Prove functions equivalence
How can we show that the following notations are equivalent?
Let $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ if this function can be written as $(C + o(1))^n, C > 1 \Leftrightarrow \ln{f(n)} \thicksim n\ln{C}$
I wanna prove it.
I can show it from left to right:
o(1) notation means that there exists such $g(n) \rightarrow 0$ and $f(n) = (C + g(n))^n)$ then we take log from both sides and get what we want.
I'm having troubles in proving it from right to left, could you please help me?
And why do we need $C > 1$?

What have you tried for the other side? It's the same kind of manipulation. As for the assumption on $C$, $C > 1$ is to guarantee that $f(n)$ is positive for big enough $n$ so that you can take the logarithm in the first place, as well as for preventing $\ln C$ from being zero.

@BrunoB, I've tried to write up the definition: ratio of functions goes to 1 as n approaches infinity, but I got nothing

Let $h : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $\ln f(n) = h(n) \cdot n \ln C$ and $h(n) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.
Then, we have:
$$f(n) = \exp \ln f(n) = \exp(h(n) \cdot n\ln C) = \left(\exp(h(n)\ln C)\right)^n$$
Since $h(n) \to 1$, $\exp(h(n)\ln C) \to \exp\ln C = C$, hence $\exp (h(n)\ln C) = C + o(1)$, which implies that:
$$f(n) = (C + o(1))^n$$
